# division math in a bash script without bc?

Tags: bash

I have a bash script where I need to calculate a percentage.  For instance, I'll have two numbers (11 and 531, lets say) and the ideal would be do calculate 11/531*100 ~= 2

I don't need decimal values, in fact I'd like to truncate and thereby round down to the nearest whole number.  It seems that to do floating point math I need to call out to bc or other utilities-- is there another way to accomplish what I'm looking for?

I don't have anything against bc but when I use it in my script, and configure the script as a nagios plugin then nagios appears for some unknown reason to refuse to proceed.  It's very odd and annoying and before digging in too much more I wondered if I could avoid bc altogether in this situation.

Comment: You can use `awk` for example: `awk 'BEGIN {printf "%.2f\n", 2/3}'`

Comment: `let result=11*100/531`

Comment: @Cyrus, `let` is no longer necessary these days -- while `(( result = 11*100/531 ))` is a bash extension, `result=$(( 11*100/531 ))` conforms to the POSIX sh standard.

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  Wondering what I would do differently if 11 and 531 were actually bash script variables?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use bash's math builtin. it just prints out the integers/whole numbers. so if you want to discard/truncate the decimal places use something like:

```
echo $(((11*100)/531)) # prints 2
```

Comment: Right. The key is to do the multiplication *first*. Otherwise, an initial division gives zero, then you multiply by 100 and still have zero.

Answer (score 3):

Try Awk - To get Floating point numbers as well

Eg:

```
NUM=44; awk -v NUM=$NUM 'BEGIN { print  ((NUM - 20) / 45) }'
```